# Camera Trajectory Estimation with Visual Odometry

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem where I have a set of images and have to calculate the camera trajectory with respect the frame of the first image.

In OpenCV there are many ways that first find features in images, match them between images and after apply visual odometry.

```
    """
    Estimate complete camera trajectory from subsequent image pairs

    Arguments:
    estimate_motion -- a function which estimates camera motion from a pair of subsequent image frames
    matches -- list of matches for each subsequent image pair in the dataset. 
               Each matches[i] is a list of matched features from images i and i + 1
    kp_list -- a list of keypoints for each image in the dataset
    k -- camera calibration matrix
    """ 

    for i in range(len(matches)):
        match = matches[i]
        kp1 = kp_list[i]
        kp2 = kp_list[i+1]
        depth = depth_maps[i]

        rmat, tvec, image1_points, image2_points = estimate_motion(match, kp1, kp2, k, depth)
        R = rmat
        t = np.array([tvec[0,0],tvec[1,0],tvec[2,0]])

        P_new = np.eye(4)
        P_new[0:3,0:3] = R.T
        P_new[0:3,3] = (-R.T).dot(t)
        P = P.dot(P_new)

        trajectory.append(P[:3,3])

    trajectory = np.array(trajectory).T   
    trajectory[2,:] = -1*trajectory[2,:]
```

In `estimate_motion` the rotation matrix and translation vector are returned but with respect image1 at that moment. As I want to obtain the trajectory in the frame of the first image I have to transform it to that frame but I do not understand:

- Why `P_new[0:3,0:3] = R.T` gets transposed
- Why `P_new[0:3,3] = (-R.T).dot(t)` the negative sign

Comment: why don't you use optical flow like it's used to calc motion of mouse controller ?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste Optical flow can be used in VO, but this is not the OP question. Here some references for [Visual Odometry](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/VO_Part_I_Scaramuzza.pdf) topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at homogeneous transformation.

Here some snapshots extracted from the [Handbook of Robotics](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hic/8803-Mobile-08/slides/1_draft.pdf):

[image]

[image]